# How to check whether reference is set to an object or not

Tags: c#, reference

There is an array with 1000 cells. I've put in there 50 object, so there is 950 cells (not used references) left.

I want to loop through 50 objects placed in array, then leave the loop.
Right now, loop is entering into array[51] and I'm getting the error:

```
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
```

I've tried condition `if (array[i] != null)` but it doesn't work.

edit: (more code)

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
    if (tablica_postaci[i] != null)
       {
       ...(actions)...
       }
    }
```

0-49 cells are filled, I haven't touched the rest. Still, there's that error.
I want my program not to take the actions after finishing with 50th element

Comment: I think we will need to see more code.

Comment: Why `if (array[i] != null)` doesn't work? Which is `array[50]` value? Did you initialize array properly? Show us more code please...

Comment: Also remember that arrays start from zero; so if you have 50 items you use array[0]..array[49]!!!

Comment: From your question, the logic you want to implement isn't clear.  Do you just want to loop through the first 50 entries,  or loop through until you reach the last object (however many entries that is).   Also remember that array indexing is zero based (it starts counting form 0 and not 1).  This may be the reason you get an error at index 51.

Comment: Please show us `tablica_postaci` definition and initialization...

Comment: Its possible that there is another variable that you are trying to access equals null. You first check seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample, you can just call break keyword to go out of the loop.

```
Company[] companies = new Company[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    companies[i] = new Company();
}

for (int i = 0; i < companies.Length; i++)
{
     if (companies[i] == null)
           {
               break;
           }

}
```

Comment: I know, i can use Your idea with break or just condition != null, Unfortunately it's not working in my program (i though there's some other way to do that and I'm doing it wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `where` clause and then loop through the array?

```
var itemsThatAreNotNull = array.Where(a => a != null);

foreach (var item in itemsThatAreNotNull)
{
    // do whatever you want to do with the item
    Console.WriteLine(item.SomeProperty);
}
```